# Elegant way of doing post-processing using Python

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

Considering the following example of post-processing using inheritance in python (from [this website](http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2014/05/19/method-overriding-in-python/#.WeXC9WiCxEY)):

```
import os

class FileCat(object):
    def cat(self, filepath):
        f = file(filepath)
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        return lines

class FileCatNoEmpty(FileCat):
    def cat(self, filepath):
        lines = super(FileCatNoEmpty, self).cat(filepath)
        nonempty_lines = [l for l in lines if l != '\n']
        return nonempty_lines
```

Basically, when we are post-processing, we don't really care about the original invocation, we just want to work with the data returned by the function.

So ideally, in my opinion, there should be no need for us to have redeclare the original function signature, just to be able to forward it to the original function.

If `FileCat` class had 100 different functions (`cat1`,`cat2`,`cat3`,...) that returned the same type of data and we wanted to use a post-processed `NoEmpty` version, then we would have to define the same 100 functions signatures in `FileCatNoEmpty` just to forward the calls.

So the question is: Is there a more elegant way of solving this problem?

That is, something like the `FileCatNoEmpty` class that would automatically make available all methods from `FileCat` but that still allows us to process the returned value?

Something like

```
class FileCatNoEmpty(FileCat):
    # Any method with whatever arguments
    def f(self,args): 
        lines = super(FileCatNoEmpty, self).f(args)    
        nonempty_lines = [l for l in lines if l != '\n']
        return nonempty_lines
```

Or maybe even another solution that does not uses inheritance.

Thanks!

Comment: Metaclasses and \from functools import wraps` may be what you're after. There's an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11350487/3527520

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer, using a wrapper class that receives the original one in the constructor (instead of inheriting from it), solves the problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4723921/3444175