# How to intercept a method call which doesn't exist?

Tags: python

I want to create a class that doesn't gives an `Attribute Error` on call of any method that may or may not exists:

**My class:**

```
class magic_class:
    ...
    # How to over-ride method calls
    ...
```

**Expected Output:**

```
ob = magic_class()
ob.unknown_method()
# Prints 'unknown_method' was called

ob.unknown_method2()
# Prints 'unknown_method2' was called
```

Now, `unknown_method` and `unknown_method2` doesn't actually exists in the class, but how can we intercept the method call in python ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intercept method calls in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704434/intercept-method-calls-in-python)

Comment: Side note FYI: PEP8 says it should be named like `class MagicClass:` and new style should at least inherit object probably: `class MagicClass(object):`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Overwrite the `__getattr__()` magic method:

```
class MagicClass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print "'%s' was called" % name
        return wrapper

ob = MagicClass()
ob.unknown_method()
ob.unknown_method2()
```

prints

```
'unknown_method' was called
'unknown_method2' was called
```

Comment: How will this deal with a method call like : `ob.calc(1000, 2000)`. Means how do you preserve the args to the call ?

Comment: @YugalJindle: Added `*args, **kwargs` to accept arbitrary parameters in the wrapper.

Answer (score 8):

Just in case someone is trying to **delegate the unknown method to an object**, here's the code:

```py
class MagicClass():
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.an_obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, method_name):
        def method(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Handling unknown method: '{}'".format(method_name))
            if kwargs:
                print("It had the following key word arguments: " + str(kwargs))
            if args:
                print("It had the following positional arguments: " + str(args))
            return getattr(self.an_obj, method_name)(*args, **kwargs)
        return method
```

This is super useful when you need to apply the [Proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

Moreover, considering both *args and kwargs*, allows you to generate an interface totally user friendly, as the ones that use MagicClass treat it as it was the real object.

Comment: what is `self.optimizer` here?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a typo. Should be `self.an_obj ` - 'optimizer' was the name of the object I was wrapping in my own program. I edited the code :)

Answer (score 2):

Override `__getattr__`; see http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html