# Define function stubs enmasse

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator

I have an object whose primary value is in applying a given decorator to every function it inherits from its super class and providing a separate version of it. For reference the decorator is below:

```
def hierarchywrapper(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for key, value in self.hierarchy.items():
            try:
                result = getattr(value, func.__name__)(*args, **kwargs)
                if result and len(result):
                    return result
                else:
                    pass
            except:
                pass
        return None
    return wrapper
```

The super class of the object containing this decorator has quite a few functions and I would prefer not to have to write out stubs for every one of them. As you can tell, the contents of these functions aren't very important and just need stubs really.

Is there some way to define function stubs en masse? Alternately is there some way I could indicate that I just want to apply this decorator to every inherited function?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is viable, but can you use a custom `__getattr__` method to catch function calls that don't exist?

Comment: @GWW Hmm... I'm not quite sure if I'm catching your drift. Could you provide some kind of example?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2704528/1726343.

Comment: `__getattr__` won't work, because it's not called if the name is resolved through normal lookups including the class tree. I see that that linked answer is very similar to mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to specialize the `__getattribute__` method on your subclass:

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    attr = super(MySuperclass, self).__getattribute__(name)
    if callable(attr):
        return hierarchywrapper(attr)
    else:
        return attr
```

@eevee suggests an even more general approach by wrapping the parent object rather than subclassing it:

```
class CallableHierarchyWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, wrapped_object):
        self.wrapped_object = wrapped_object

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = self.wrapped_object.__getattribute__(name)
        if callable(attr):
            return hierarchywrapper(attr)
        else:
            return attr
```

Comment: Oooh. I see! Great solution, just what I was looking for.

Comment: better yet, wrap instead of subclassing, and this will work with any class  :)  also note that special methods do not trigger `__getattribute__`.

Comment: @eevee - what would you wrap? I'm not disagreeing, I'm just not sure where you'd do that.

Comment: instead of `obj = Subclass()`, do `obj = Wrapper(Superclass())`.  this wrapping doesn't seem to have anything to do with the actual state of the class, so no need to tangle into its inheritance hierarchy

Comment: I see, and then keep the `Superclass` instance around as member data? Yeah, that would work too; I'll edit it in as an alternative.